# Converting A Maybe Value Into A Normal Value

Tags: elm

I have no clue how to convert a Maybe value to a normal value ...

I have these lines...

```
pickChord : Model -> Note -> Chord
pickChord model note =
    let
        nextChord = List.head (List.filter (testChord note) model.possibleMajorChords)
    in
        nextChord
```

The compiler complains:

> The definition of `pickChord` does not match its type annotation. - The type annotation for `pickChord` says it always returns:
>
> **Chord**
>
> But the returned value (shown above) is a:
>
> **Maybe Chord**

How could I handle this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why I love Elm. In it's own way, Elm is telling you you've got a design flaw.

Let's take a closer look. Here's the code as-is:

```
pickChord : Model -> Note -> Chord
pickChord model note =
    let
        nextChord = List.head (List.filter (testChord note) model.possibleMajorChords)
    in
        nextChord
```

So you've got a list of major chords which you then filter for a specific note. That produces a `List` of chords. However, the `List` type can represent an empty list, which is why `List.head` returns a `Maybe`. In your case, `List.head` can return either a `Nothing` or `Just Chord`.

Now, you *can* work around this with default values and error handling, but those are just work-arounds which dodge the real problem: **The List type doesn't accurately fit your problem domain.**

If you've got a list of *all* the major chords, I can't think of a reason why you would ever end up with an empty list after applying the filter. The filter should always find at least one chord. Assuming that's the case, what you need is a `List`-like type which can represent a list which is *never* empty; Which means `head` would always return a `Chord` and not a `Maybe Chord`. That would be a much better representation of what you're trying to achieve. Luckly, there's already such a type (which I didn't create but I use extensively) called `List.Nonempty`. Here's how it would work:

```
import List.Nonempty as NE

pickChord : Model -> Note -> Chord
pickChord model note =        
    NE.head (NE.filter (testChord note) model.possibleMajorChords)
```

Your `model.possibleMajorChords` would have to change from a `List Chord` to a `List.Nonempty Chord`, but it makes the whole *maybe problem* go away. That is of course assuming that my claim about the filter always returning at least one chord holds true.

Here's a link to the Nonempty package: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/elm-nonempty-list/latest

Comment: actually... filter requires a default value. So you may need a different type, but the point is List is probably not it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of Maybe cords you want to unwrap it then:

```
pickChord : Model -> Note -> Chord
pickChord model note =
    let
        nextChord = List.head (List.filter (testChord note) model.possibleMajorChords)
    in

    case nextChord of                  
      Nothing ->                              
      //some error here if you want

      Just cord ->                             
        cord
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `List.head` won't give you an element in case of an empty list, you'll either have to provide a default value

```
pickChord : Model -> Note -> Chord
pickChord model note =
    withDefault <chord> (List.head (List.filter (testChord note) model.possibleMajorChords))
```

Or leave the default `Chord` to the caller.

```
pickChord : Model -> Note -> Maybe Chord
pickChord model note =
    List.head (List.filter (testChord note) model.possibleMajorChords)
```